# Can you customize the ui in the google maps turn by turn navigation activity in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I'm developing an android application related to maps and navigation. I want to show some information to user while turn by turn navigation activity is up on the screen, but Since the navigation activity takes up whole of my screen I can't show anything. Is there any way to edit the UI of that screen or any other alternate of how can I show some information on top of turn by turn navigation?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

   //Add your Layout here, It overlaps the Map Screen

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No you are editing the map fragment, i know i can do that .. like i said i want to edit the ui in the Navigation activity.